# Como publicar minha biblioteca em um repositório linux?

Tags: c, biblioteca, unix, repository

Desenvolvi uma biblioteca em C e quero disponibilizá-la para outros desenvolvedores. Gostaria que essa biblioteca pudesse ser instalada usando o comando `apt-get`, por exemplo:

`sudo apt-get install minhalib`

e no código os desenvolvedores incluiriam os headers...

`#include <minhalib.h>`

e compilariam *linkando* a biblioteca:

`gcc -o main.c -lminhalib main`

---

Como faço para disponibilizar a biblioteca dessa maneira?

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa então é de um *sistema de automação de software*. Existem diversas formas de isso ser feito, mas eu mesmo nunca lidei com nenhuma delas a sério, hehe!

Esse é um assunto realmente vasto - só a página da Wikipedia sobre [sistemas de automação de software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) ([ptBR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_softwares_de_automa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compila%C3%A7%C3%A3o_e_montagem))já é bem grandinha. Como é de se esperar, cada um tem seus prós e contras.

Mas, para encurtar sua procura, eu daria três recomendações: [waf](https://waf.io/), [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/) e [cmake](https://cmake.org). Eles são versáteis e fáceis de aprender, e as principais distribuições e canais de instalação de software têm um bom suporte. O Waf eu recomendaria para projetos pequenos, e o Cmake para os maiores. (As [GNU Autotools](https://airs.com/ian/configure/) são famosas e muito usadas, mas acho elas complicadas demais. Não recomendo.)

Depois disso, bem, você já pode abrir uma conta no [Github](https://github.com), [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com), [Sourceforge](http://sf.net), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) ou o que seja, e liberar seu software para o mundo! (Aí é a hora que você vai pensar em que [licença](https://opensource.org/licenses) escolher...).

P.S.: Quanto ao `apt-get`, isto é especificamente um comando de instalação de pacotes. Cada distribuição lida disso à sua maneira. Em razão disso, eu recomendaria deixar esta criação de pacotes a cargo dos desenvolvedores de cada distro.